# Changing the database value based on dropdown list (PHP, MYSQLi)

Tags: php, html, mysqli, assign

Since I am new to an advanced side of PHP, I would like to know how to change the database value by using a dropdown option list.

**Users view of the page: This is what the user will see on the webpage. The users should be able to assign the sensors by selecting the sensors with the checkbox and using the drop down list to assign the sensor to a particular school.**
[image: This is what the user will see on the webpage. The users should be able to assign the sensors by selecting the sensors with the checkbox and using the drop down list to assign the sensor to a particular school.]

**SenSG Table: This is the table, Sensg, where all the sensors' information are stored. The school_id is the value which I would want to change when the users checkbox a sensor and choose a school in the dropdown.**
[image: This is the table, Sensg, where all the sensors' information are stored. The school_id is the value which I would want to change.]

**School Table: This is the table, School, where all the schools with their respective school_id. The school_id is not auto-incremented.**

[image: This is the table, School, where all the schools with their respective school id.]

How do I go about in changing the school_id of SenSG table when I assign a particular or more sensors to a respective school using a dropdown list and it will change its value based on the dropdown list.

For example,
If I check-boxed the first sensor and choose the dropdown box of option 'Republic Poly', the school_id in the SenSG table should change according to the dropdown value.

How do I go about doing this in PHP as I am completely lost.

Thank you.

Comment: There is an edit button, please post the explaination in your question, not in the comments

Comment: Hello. I'm sorry. It's nothing to do with the edit button actually. That's another feature in my website. It's about the checkbox and the dropdown list.

Comment: A dropdown works just like any other form input. You need to be more specific and post code for what you've tried already. Also, looks like the `school_id` field is the primary key, which you should not try to change, especially if it's auto-incremented.

Comment: No, I meant edit your question. There's an edit button below your question, that's so you can go back and edit your question.

Comment: NVM I did it for you

Comment: Thank you for the changes. The school_id is not auto-incremented. I just assigned a value to each school. Currently the first three sensors are assigned to Raffles Junior College, as you can see in the SenSG table. I would like to checkbox these three sensors and pick a dropdown option of 'Republic Poly', it will assigned the check-boxed sensors from '3' to '2' in SenSG table. It will not affect the School table.

Comment: There's a couple ways you can do this.  If you want to use pure PHP (as opposed to AJAX) you can do this. 1) Make sure that your checkboxes inputs have the value of the respective serial number. 2) have a form submit button that initiates the POST.  3) Your form action can either direct back to the same page to another one, or back to itself.  There you can have a UPDATE query in PHP.

Comment: Here's a resource you can look at - http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-post.html